# Saving file from SQL Server into Memory Stream in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, memorystream

I've method which saves the file saved in db into file on disk. How would I modify it so method returns MemoryStream?

```
    public static void databaseFileRead(string varID, string varPathToNewLocation) {
        using (var varConnection = Locale.sqlConnectOneTime(Locale.sqlDataConnectionDetailsDZP))
        using (var sqlQuery = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [RaportPlik] FROM [dbo].[Raporty] WHERE [RaportID] = @varID", varConnection)) {
            sqlQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@varID", varID);
            using (var sqlQueryResult = sqlQuery.ExecuteReader()) {
                if (sqlQueryResult != null) {
                    sqlQueryResult.Read();
                    var blob = new Byte[(sqlQueryResult.GetBytes(0, 0, null, 0, int.MaxValue))];
                    sqlQueryResult.GetBytes(0, 0, blob, 0, blob.Length);
                    using (var fs = new FileStream(varPathToNewLocation, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
                        fs.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change FileStream to MemoryStream. Declare the stream object at the top level of the method and use it on the return statement

Comment: it would be excellent if someone could paste entire code, so others can study how it is done... There are also young programmers on Stackoverflow who doesn't have any experience with memorystream and getting data from Blob file...